# copy paste fiction in vba

Tags: numbers, copy, paste

I would like to use copy, paste function in VBA, but when I am pasting  from text format in to general I am receiving less digits when I am copying 11 digits number. 
Example:
00001234567 should be copied, but is only 1234567
How to do it ? Help needed. ☺

Comment: Are your cells formatted properly?

Comment: Not sure as I need compare to 11 digits number but what should I do if the number is shorter...

Comment: That Was cery helpful, even without any extra programming. Thank you